# Loopback model validation is running before 'before save' observer

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback, Angular2 and [ng-bootstrap date picker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker) in an application and having trouble saving dates.

I'm using `@angular/http` to send a POST request to a Loopback backend that includes a ng-bootstrap date picker input. The date picker format is:

```
{
    day: 15, 
    month: 6, 
    year: 2017
}
```

which I can see in the headers of my request, however Loopback expects dates to be saved as a JavaScript Date Object.

Before I attempt to save my date data, I want to convert it from the format above to a native JavaScript Object. However, if I run the following code the console shows `Invalid Date`.

```
MyModel.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    console.log('date: ', ctx.instance.date);
});
```

The [loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save) states that the `before save` observer triggers before the request validators are called, but that doesn't look like the case in this instance.

What is the correct *loopback* method of accessing the POST request and modifying it before the validators sink their teeth into it and throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the remote hooks are hit before the validators.  You might want to try:

```
MyModel.beforeRemote('create', (ctx, [instance], next)=>{
    // handle code here
    // don't forget to validate the data on 'updateById' too
    next();
});
```